# Load Raw Resource Inside Android Library

Tags: android, android-library

I am developing an Android Library that contains some files with data. I want to package this library into an AAR file and distribute it. I'm having trouble opening the resource files within this library.

Here is a scenario that is analogous to mine:

In the Library there is a file `labels.txt` which is stored in `res/raw`.

I have a class `LabelReader` that sits inside the library. It has a function `read()` that will return the string contents of `labels.txt`.

```
package com.library.mine

class LabelReader {

  fun read():string {
     val resourceID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("labels.txt", "raw", "com.library.mine") //returns 0
    //Exception here
    val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(identifier)))

   ...
  }

}
```

I try to use the function in the app and that triggers the exception:

```
package com.app.mine

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val labelReader = LabelReader()
        val labels = LabelReader.read() //problem        


    }
}
```

From what I have read it's not possible to include the file in the assets directory of an android library.

Most questions I have googled seem to make use of the Activity's Context, but that's not available to me here.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: what does it mean *Activity's Context,but that's not available to me here*

Comment: I am, as you can probably tell, a beginner with android, but inside an Activity I can do something like `this.applicationContext.resources.openRawResource(`, but I'm not able to do that in this class because it's in a library which doesn't have access to applicationContext.

Comment: Don't confuse context with an application context. In any case you can define in your `read` method a `context` parameter.

Comment: Then what is the correct context to use to find my file? Do I need the library's context? How would I get that? I can't find any examples of this specific problem, most examples seem to be trying to access resources contained in the library from inside an app

Answer (score 0):

In my AAR libraries, I use to include and use raw resources. To use them, in the library or in the client application you need to do the same things:

- Use the *openRawResource* method of *Resources* object (from Context).
- Use raw resource name (letter/number and _) without the file extension.

A simple method to read raw resource content as text:

```java
 public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int rawResourceId) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(rawResourceId);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String read = in.readLine();
        while (read != null) {
            buffer.append(read + "\n");
            read = in.readLine();
        }

        inputStream.close();

        buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

I hope this helps.